# MySQL DB Schema For Logging PPC ADs Performance, day-to-day

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, reporting

I am trying to finish up the re-build of an advertising system for a site. The reporting/logging end of the new PPC model is providing some difficulty, and i've found myself lost for better ideas. The table in question will be called "reports" and will contain the ad_id, impressions, clicks, and CTR% for each ad in the system, everyday for 1 rolling year.

The simple solution looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reports` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ad_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `impressions` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `clicks` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ctr` float(6,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `report_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The problem comes in when you look at the days of the week. I want to be able to collect numbers for each advertiser and show reports day by day. We will have multiple advertisers, with multiple ads each. The most obvious (and ridiculous) option is to build a table for each day of the year.

If i use the "report_date" column, my reports table will eventually turn into a mess. Controlling updates for this data in this instance would include the common:

```
if there is no record for today - INSERT new record
else UPDATE existing record for today
```

I am updating this record with PHP calculations on each click. But next year, continue the same process? i guess that would work, but i'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. I would rather have a rolling year complete - filled with zeros for days without advertised. Clients using this system will be able to re-fill their bank at any time and re-instate old ads, which will never be removed from the system. This is the reasoning behind the rolling year model.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are in need of a datamart.  Storing historical information in a transactional system is going to cause you headaches all the time.  Querying/Updating rows in your transactional system will be very slow. My recommendation leave the table as is minus the report_Date.

My recommendation is a dimensional model not relational.  Create a database for reporting and in this database use a snapshot fact like below.  It sounds like there will be some other interesting dimensions. This will allow users to see clicks/ctr by url or day.  Your entrance into the giant fact is based off of optimized indexed keys.  Google dimensional modeling for more information.  Combining history/reporting/transactional will usually result in bad design.  If you need any help on how to populate that post a comment.
[image: dimensional add model]

Comment: i've been working on the efficiency of the querying, and to my surprise, the original design, with the addition of some new date fields will work out very well as far as i can tell. I will reduce the length of record keeping down to 30 days (Facebook only keeps about 28) for the initial testing period. My DB schema uses a similar design to your suggestion - but i only posted the code for the 1 table. The end result is clean and compact, so i will give it a run. Thanks for the additional ideas!